# Copying Data From One Table to a new table that is all foreign keys

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table with over half a million rows and four columns.

The columns can be called col1, col2, col3, and col4.

Each column in this master table is a varchar2 and there is redundant data.

I am converting this table to have it all foreign keys instead. As such I have created 4 tables for each column. Col1_Table, Col2_Table, Col3_Table, and Col4_Table. And finally a new master table that is similar to the original master table except instead of varchar2s. I'm using numbers and have created foreign key constraints.

The tables are as such:

```
--OriginalMasterTable

Col1 VarChar2

Col2 VarChar2

Col3 VarChar2

Col4 VarChar2




--Col1_Table, Col2_Table, Col3_Table, Col4_Table

ID - Number

Name - VarChar2

--NewMasterTable

Col1_ID Number

Col2_ID Number

Col3_ID Number

Col4_ID Number
```

The col1,2,3,and 4 tables have the original data from the original master table with new ids.

I want to replicate the original master table into the new master table but instead with the foreign keys from the col1,2,3, and 4 tables.

How would I go about this using SQL or PL/SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use joins, but on the character fields.  Assuming all the fields are defined, then you can use inner joins:

```
select c1.id as col1_id, c2.id as col2_id, c3.id as col3_id, c4.id as col4_id
from originalmastertable omt join
     col1_table c1
     on omt.col1 = c1.name join
     col2_table c2
     on omt.col2 = c2.name join
     col3_table c3
     on omt_col3 = c3.name join
     col4_rable c4
     on omt_col4 = c4.name;
```

You can then put the results into a new table.